# Disable the array element if the array element is existed in any of the other arrays

Tags: javascript, html

I have below arrays, If Array1 element is already existed in any of the other arrays which are array2,array3,array4 then that element needs to be disabled, so that i can not able to select that option from the below dropdown

```
$scope.Array1 = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
$scope.Array2 = ["A"];
$scope.Array3 = ["B"];
$scope.Array4 = ["C"];


<select multiple class="form-control" id="temp" name="temp" ng-model="data" chosen ng-options="array as array for array in Array1">
<option disabled></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Can you please show us what you have tried so far, and what's not working? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution below

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="AppController">
    <select 
      multiple 
      class="form-control" 
      id="temp" 
      name="temp" 
      ng-model="data" 
      chosen
      style="height: 10em;width: 6em;"
    >
      <option ng-repeat="value in Array1 " ng-disabled="existsInOtherArrays(value)"> {{value}}</option>
    </select>
    <br>Selected {{data}}
</div>

function AppController($scope) {
    $scope.Array1 = ["O","A","B","C","D","E","F"];
    $scope.Array2 = ["A"];
    $scope.Array3 = ["B"];
    $scope.Array4 = ["C"];
        $scope.data = "F";
        $scope.existsInOtherArrays = function (value) {
      return ($scope.Array2.concat($scope.Array3).concat($scope.Array4).indexOf(value) !== -1) ;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/om7k8d1c/29/

Comment: the above code is almost working but not binding the existed list of values to the ng-model, it is showing as select some options not the existed list